# How to delete files in subfolders starting by 'something'

Tags: batch-file

I would like to delete a specific file (*.jpg) in many subfolders beginning by 'an' but I don't want to remove jpeg files from the other subfolders.

I tried the command :

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir "your_path\an*" /b /ad') do echo (cd %%A & echo del /F /Q /S "*.jpg")
```

but this command delete all the jpg files in all subfolders.

The directory is not very difficult:

```
C:
  Users
    user_name
        My pictures
            goo [Main folder]
                inn_01 (sub folder)
                    a.jpg (to remove)
                inn_02 (sub folder)
                    a.jpg (to remove)
                ...
                001 (sub folder)
                    a.jpg (to keep)
                002 (sub folder)
                    a.jpg (to keep)
                ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please, very straight forward. Remove `echo` once you are ready to actually delete.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "your_path\inn*" /b /ad') do (
        echo del /F /Q "%%~fi\*.jpg"
)
```

Note, do NOT add the `/S` in the del command please.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/S` from the `del` command:

```
<Prompt>del /?
Deletes one or more files.

DEL [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names
ERASE [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names

  names         Specifies a list of one or more files or directories.
                Wildcards may be used to delete multiple files. If a
                directory is specified, all files within the directory
                will be deleted.

  /S            Delete specified files from all subdirectories.
```

**Edit after comment**

As this seems not to work, what about `ForFiles`? Something like:

```
forfiles /s /C "cmd /c echo @path\@file"
```

(You can add an `IF`-clause in the `"cmd /c` part)

Comment: I did that too. But if i remove /s , the script doesn't do anything